# Adobe Products Central Management

Tags: update, adobe

Is there a centralizes management product for Adobe Reader and Adobe Flash? Some of my clients have workstations and a SBS server, and I was hoping there is a product from Adobe (preferably free) that will centralize installing updates so I don't have to go around to individual PC's to do updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly, but you can deploy Adobe Reader and Flash player with Group Policy Objects. I do it, and it's very effective in getting these products updated swiftly (if your users are anything like mine, they won't press the big flashy message telling them to update).

Check out the pages on Adobe's website about deploying [Adobe Reader](http://www.adobe.com/products/reader/distribution.html) and [Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/products/players/fpsh_distribution1.html) via GPOs. Basically, you sign up for a (free) distribution agreement and they will send you links to an MSI you can deploy to your client computers. They also link to an FTP site which contains `.msp` files that you patch your central installation with when Adobe releases an update.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [LanGuard](http://www.gfi.com/lannetscan) by GFI. It does Adobe, Java, Firefox, and all sorts of other patching.

Free? No. Awesome? Yes.